# Writing to EventLog from Outlook VSTO Plugin

Tags: c#, outlook, registry, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to write to the eventlog from a VSTO Outlook Plugin, but I haven't figured out how.

I've tried this a few different ways and I'm still not sure if I'm hitting a security permission issue between the Outlook plugin and the eventlog or something code related.

I tried with 2 different pieces of code. This is my testing piece and even it doesn't write:

```
EventLog myLog = new EventLog("Application");
                myLog.Source = "ReportPhishing";
                myLog.WriteEntry("Reporting Email");
```

This is the code I'm ultimately trying to add in:

```
string sourceName = "ReportPhishing";
                //Defines who was the sender email
                string SenderEmail = obj_CurrentItem.SenderEmailAddress;
                //Defines who the end receiving email address is
                string ReceiverEmail = obj_CurrentItem.ReceivedByName;
                //Defines the schema used to pull the header information out of the email
                string EmailHeaders = obj_CurrentItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E");
                //Defines FileName as from the subject line
                string FileName = obj_CurrentItem.Subject;
                //Specifies the main event context
                string eventSubject = "Reported Phishing Email";
                //Creates the payload information for sending to the local eventlog
                string eventPayload = eventSubject + "%n%nSenderEmail: " + SenderEmail + "%n%nReceivingEmail: " + ReceiverEmail + "%n%nSubject: " + FileName + "%n%nHeaders: " + EmailHeaders;
                //string eventpayload = @"<EventData><Data Name=""SenderEmail"">"+ SenderEmail +"</Data><Data Name=""ReceivingEmail"">" + SenderEmail + "</Data><Data Name=""Subject"">" + FileName + "</Data><Data Name=""Headers"">" + EmailHeaders + "</Data></EventData>";
                EventLog.WriteEntry(sourceName, eventPayload, EventLogEntryType.Error);
```

What I've tried:

1. I tried to create the event source from the plugin, but that never worked as it wouldn't execute without admin permissions.
2. I manually created the source via the registry, but that didn't seem to work either.
3. I removed the registry entry and created the source via an elevated command line using `eventcreate`. By creating it via commandline, I confirmed that a non-elevated command line could still write to the event source

[image]

4. Verified permissions from the Registry (I added a lot more permissions as a just in case)[image]

[image]

5. Read through a number of other StackOverflow posts around the EventLog. None really discussed the plugin aspect. Most focused on permission issues or incorrect implementation of MS code examples.
6. Created a basic form application that created a log event. This appears to work with my above sample code:[image][image]

There appears to be something within the VSTO Plugin functionality that prevents logging to the EventLog. I'm unsure where to go from here.

Comment: According to the docs, you can't create an event source without elevated privileges. See the notes of [EventLog.CreateEventSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.createeventsource?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_EventLog_CreateEventSource_System_String_System_String_). Maybe you can use some registered sources from Outlook (if any)?

Comment: Correct. Which is why I created an event source via command line. That's #3 above. That's also how I was able to write via an un-elevated CMD to the event source.

Comment: And still not able to write with that source from within your vsto plugin?

Comment: Yeah I'm getting nothing. I tried elevating my Outlook to Admin and still didn't make a difference.

I'm leaning towards this being a coding issue or some Windows/MS control that inherently prevents the plugin from writing down to the eventlog.

Comment: Just an idea: are you sure your code gets called in the VSTO plugin? Do you get any exception? What if you use 'Outlook' as source?

Comment: I found that I can log with the "startup" void but not with an onclick void. Still looking into it

Comment: Try to run exactly the same code in both applications - a VSTO add-in and windows forms application. Do you still get different results? Are both applications run under the same security context? Try to run without debugging outside of VS.